# Where should I call a print function for Non-compatible type conversion in C#.NET?

Tags: c#

In what line of this C#.NET code below would be the best way to print (`Console.WriteLine()`) the output of non-compatible type conversion:

```
string Start = "2757457";
int Middle = Convert.ToInt32(Start); // is it: Console.WriteLine(Middle)
int End = int.Parse(Start); // or is it: Console.WriteLine(End)
```

Comment: Could you clarify the question? What is `nonCompatiblesStart`?

Comment: Whoops! I posted the code wrongly, sorry about that.

Comment: It's still not clear what you're asking. You can print any of these values via `Console.WriteLine`. What's your goal? What have you tried so far?

Comment: I mean using the `Console.WriteLine` method currently. They both work but I am wondering what one is the best to use (`Middle` or `End`). Sorry for the confusion!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think your question has anything to do with printing to the console and everything to do with should you use `Parse` or `Convert`. Assuming that's correct then you may find the following breakdown of `Convert, Parse, & TryParse` applicable. If it's not correct, clarify and I'll either edit my answer or delete as applicable.

`Parse` Takes a string and (assuming it is a number) outputs the number equivalent of it. It will throw an exception if the value is null, not a number, or outside the min/max range of Int.

`Convert.ToInt32` Takes a string and (assuming it is a number) checks if it's null. If null it returns 0 otherwise it calls Parse.

`TryParse` Takes a string and if it's not a number returns false. If it is a number it'll return true. If it's null, it will return 0 in the out parameter (but return false as it's primary return value). If it is a number, it'll return the number as an out parameter.

Comment: Thanks for the clariforcation, looks like `Convert.ToInt32` is probably the best option for me (following a small course that did not explain what any of this particuar code means).

Comment: Actually, TryParse is almost always the best solution (it doesn't through exceptions on bad input).  Use code like: if (!int.TryParse(myString, out int intValue) { /*do something about the fact that you can't parse it */ }

Comment: Agreed with @Flydog57. If you're taking user input and converting it, ALWAYS use TryParse. Parse and/or Convert.ToInt32 are only good if you know for sure that the thing being passed in will be a number in string form.

Comment: Thanks for the help, will use it in the future.